# IntelliJ IDEA Won't let me choose Font. Also kerning Unbearable. Are these related?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I can't change the font in IntelliJ IDEA (just started trying to use it). Can't figure out why kerning is absolutely terrible, could they be related.

Here's what I'm talking about, in File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Font.

The *only* thing I can change related to fonts is the *scheme name*.

- Kerning is okay for the default.

[image]

- I really wanted to use a different font and dark theme though. The only other option is Darcula. As you may also experience from what is below, the kerning will raise your blood pressure.

[image]

How can I fix this? I am on Windows 7 x64, Intellij IDEA 14.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new schema in order to choose another font. Just click "Save as..." button to save the preset and customize it.